# Hangfire limitting jobs count depending on server cpu / memory status

Tags: hangfire

I can distribute my jobs between servers using queue names. Also, I can set workerCount. However, I need to dynamically decide to execute a job depending on server cpu / memory status. Also, I need to pick the best server in runtime depending on again cpu / memory metrics.
Can I create such a business logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of doing that but not sure why you would want to do that. [Number of workers](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html) are normally based on the number of CPUs you have so that you dont get workers that dont have enough resources to work with.

If you do want to use the cpu/memory metrics and check the system state before queueing any job, note that you will be adding extra overhead each time just to check "all" servers metrics before you would queue the next job.

One way to do this would be to create a queue name based on each of the server you have in the pool. Then, use [UseQueueFromParameterAttribute] attribute to run your logic and select the queue based on what you find from each server's metrics.

[Discussion and example on how to use UseQueueFromParameterAttribute](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/one-queue-for-the-whole-farm-and-one-queue-by-server/490/3)